# How to achieve probability of an event < 1/2 in Java?

Tags: java, random, probability

I have a small application where I'm allocating some memory based on :

```
if (RANDOM.nextBoolean()) {
     // Allocate some memory here.
}
```

To improve the coverage, unit tests are repeated multiple times and JVM complaints of being out of heap space. There is no pre-condition for the allocation, I just want some random distribution and avoid the error message.

Is there a way to achieve probability of memory allocation to be < 1/2?

Comment: You could also put that condition into a protected method and override it for your unit tests. That way you can make your tests controllable and repeatable more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e.g. for about  an 1/4 chance

```
if (RANDOM.nextDouble() < 0.25) {
     // Allocate some memory here.
}
```

Adjust the value to compare against accordingly. [nextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29)() returns values from 0.0 up to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example, probability is less than 1/2:

```
if (RANDOM.nextBoolean() && RANDOM.nextBoolean()) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your source of randomness an external instance that you can pass into the class that uses it.  In your tests, pass it in as a **mock** object.  You will be able to control the behavior of the mock object so that it returns a predictable result for your tests.  Then you can make the probability anything you want for your tests.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final BooleanRandom bRandom;

    public MyClass(BooleanRandom bRandom) {
        this.bRandom = bRandom;
    }

    public void doTheMemoryThing() {
        if (bRandom.nextBoolean()) {
            allocateMemory();

    }
}
```

In your test, using Mockito:

```
BooleanRandom br = mock(BooleanRandom.class);
when(br.nextBoolean()).thenReturn(true);  // or false, as needed
MyClass mc = new MyClass(br);
// test
mc.doTheMemoryThing();
```

In this invocation of `doTheMemoryThing` you *know* that the test will pass.  In other cases, you can wirte `nextBoolean` to return `false` so that the memory does not get allocated.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution to this is to use whatever probability you want, in this example, 13% of the time you want a true value:

```
public static final boolean getRandomTrue(final double probability) {
    return java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() < probability;
}


private static final double PERCENT13 = 13/100.0
```

Then, on some other code, you can do:

```
if (getRandomTrue(PERCENT13)) {
    // do someting 13% of the time....
}
```